# Why UICollectionViewCell images are not loaded although the image var is not nil in debugger?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uistoryboard

I am using a collection view to show choices for categories in a news app.
My collection view images are not loaded in the cell. On checking in the debugger the image var contains the image.
The images are to be loaded from Assets.xcassets folder.
when priniting out the value of image of the cell view in debugger it shows nil.

PS: The cells and their labels are loading fine, just the .png images are not loaded.

```swift
import UIKit

class CategoriesViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var categoriesCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    private var newsCategories = ["Buisness","Sports","Health","Science","Entertainment","Technology","General","Everything"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        categoriesCollectionView.delegate = self
        categoriesCollectionView.dataSource = self
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return newsCategories.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CategoriesCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? CategoriesCollectionViewCell{
            cell.imageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: newsCategories[indexPath.item])
            cell.label.text = "\(newsCategories[indexPath.item])"
            return cell
        }else{ return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PlaceholderCell", for: indexPath) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your issue but there's no need to use `if let cell...`. Just force-cast the dequeued cell. Get rid of the placeholder cell. It's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

This combination

```
private var newsCategories = ["Buisness","Sports","Health","Science","Entertainment","Technology","General","Everything"]
```

And

```
UIImage(contentsOfFile: newsCategories[indexPath.item])
```

Isn't correct with `contentsOfFile` you need to reference full file path the images are downloaded in

**Or**  use

```
UIImage(named:newsCategories[indexPath.item])
```

if the images are shipped in app main bundle

Comment: This one worked=>>       cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: newsCategories[indexPath.item], in: nil, compatibleWith: nil)